# Gammafunction for $-k<\operatorname{Re}(z)<-k+1$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

I need to show, that
$$
\Gamma\left(z\right) =
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z - 1}\left[{\rm e}^{-t} -\sum_{\ell = 0}^{k - 1}
\left(-1\right)^{\ell}\,
\frac{t^{\ell}}{\ell!}\right]{\rm d}t
$$
is for $-k < \operatorname{Re}\left(z\right)<
-k + 1$.

And I don't find the right path to get it. Could someone give me a hint or help me $?$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For $\Re(z) > 0$ $$\Gamma(z)-\sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (z+k)}=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}(e^{-t}-1_{t< 1}\sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} t^k)dt\tag{1}$$
The RHS converges for $\Re(z) > -K$ and it gives the analytic continuation to this half-plane.

For $\Re(z)\in (-K,1-K)$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (z+k)}= -\int_1^\infty 
t^{z-1}\sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} t^k dt\tag{2}$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ you get your result.

Comment: Hi reuns, thank you for your fast answer. I understand (2) and also how to get the result from (1) and (2). Could you just explain, why is (1) valid or how exactly you got this equation. Thanks

Comment: I just used that $\int_0^1 t^{z-1+k}dt = 1/(z+k)$ for $\Re(z+k)>0$